# Flutter source code, why should we put assertion here?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I read flutter source code, Text widget, I founded this:

```
const Text(
    String this.data, {
    Key? key,
    this.style,
    this.strutStyle,
    this.textAlign,
    this.textDirection,
    this.locale,
    this.softWrap,
    this.overflow,
    this.textScaleFactor,
    this.maxLines,
    this.semanticsLabel,
    this.textWidthBasis,
    this.textHeightBehavior,
  }) : assert(
         data != null,
         'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
       ),
       textSpan = null,
       super(key: key);
```

I can't get why should we put assertion `data!=null` here?
My thought is that this.data would always be assign(because it is not optional), and never be null.
Or is there any concern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is still useful for projects that are not running with null safety yet.

Flutter is now fully null-safe, and you are right: it *"should"* never be `null` because the type is not nullable.

---

This comes from when Flutter and dart were not supporting null safety yet. Before null safety, you could have done `Text(null)` and the linter wouldn't have complained.

**So why is it still there now that Flutter is null safe?**

Flutter puts a lot of effort into not introducing breaking changes and supports older versions.
So an old flutter project that didn't migrate to null-safety will run without the null safety feature and could do `Text(null)`.